# Extend browse for folder dialog in Win XP

Tags: windows-xp

Is it possible to add custom entries to the default "browse for folder" dialog in Windows XP? Is there an easy Registry hack available?

Comment: I basically need link to a (longpath) directory as high as possible within the tree.

Comment: You should edit this information into your question - it will make it more obvious to people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download TweakUI > (install and run it, obviously ;) > Common Dialogs > Places Bar

Comment: this seems only to allow you to add some of Windows' Special Folders, no user folders.

Comment: It's not real obvious, but you can type your own path into one of the selection boxes (right over top of **<none>**)